# Ubuntu 9.10 freezes when HDMI port is connected

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, graphics-card, hdmi, xorg

I have a Sony Vaio FW350 with a HDMI output. I'm trying to use it under Ubuntu 9.10 with a LG LCD monitor 21,5'. The laptop has a Intel 4500 video card.  I've tried two approaches:

1. Boot the laptop with the HDMI cable connected and monitor turned on. Result: LCD Monitor keeps turned on but the whole screen is black and Ubuntu do not seem to be initializing.
2. Boot Ubuntu until the end. I then connect the HDMI cable into the Laptop. The mouse and the whole system freezes.

In both cases the only way to turn off the laptop is holding the power button.

I've looked around the internet for similar problems, but only found workarounds for the same problem with VGA input, not HDMI. 
I also tried to use metacity before connecting the cable, but still got the same result.

Any hints?

Comment: Possibly fixed in newer kernels.

Comment: @codeape I'm with the last kernel shipped with 11.10, still have the same problem

Comment: try a newer kernel?